# jquery clear input default value

Tags: jquery

How can I clear the default value of an input form onfocus with jquery and clear it again when tha submit button is pressed?

```
<html>
        <form method="" action="">
            <input type="text" name="email" value="Email address" class="input" />
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="button" />
        </form>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //hide input text
    $(".input").click(function(){
        if ($('.input').attr('value') == ''){
            $('.input').attr('value') = 'Email address'; alert('1');}
        if  ($('.input').attr('value') == 'Email address'){
            $('.input').attr('value') = ''}
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you use the native `placeholder` attribute instead? There are various [polyfills](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) available to make it work in older browsers.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Why you not posted it as an answer? I think is the easiest and best solution.

Comment: @jelies - I didn't post it as an answer because while it does the same thing as what the OP is trying to do, it doesn't really answer what's wrong with their code. But I agree, it is definitely the easiest solution!

Comment: Yes it is a good answer and I have upvoted it, but I do not want to use the placeholder tag.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You may use this..

```
<body>
    <form method="" action="">
        <input type="text" name="email" class="input" />
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="button" />
    </form>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".input").val("Email Address");
        $(".input").on("focus", function() {
            $(".input").val("");
        });
        $(".button").on("click", function(event) {
            $(".input").val("");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Talking of your own code, the problem is that the attr api of jquery is set by

```
$('.input').attr('value','Email Adress');
```

and not as you have done:

```
$('.input').attr('value') = 'Email address';
```

Comment: I have decided to use this answer as it seems the most elegant.

Comment: thnx.i myself am new to jquery.this is my 1st accepted anser here,and third overall(as you can probably deduce by my reputation points)

Comment: Why `$('.input').removeAttr('value')` does not work?

Answer (score 18):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //...
//clear on focus
$('.input').focus(function() {
    $('.input').val("");
});
   //clear when submitted
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.input').val("");
});
```

});

Comment: This is wrong `$('.input').attr('value') = 'Email address';`, should be `$('.input').attr('value', 'Email address');` how is this answer upvoted?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Edited the answer, thank you. That code wasn't related to the question anyway. I copied it from topicstarter's code.

Answer (score 10):

```
$('.input').on('focus', function(){
    $(this).val('');
});

$('[type="submit"]').on('click', function(){
    $('.input').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Unless you're really worried about older browsers, you could just use the new html5 `placeholder` attribute like so:

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" class="input" />
```

Comment: "Unless your really worried about older browser"... you can polyfill the `placeholder` attribute so it works in older browsers too. See my comment on the question, and see the [Modernizr wiki](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) for other examples.

Comment: Yeah that's true, or you could just write a bit of JQuery to pull the attribute yourself if your keen.

Answer (score 3):

Try that:

```
  var defaultEmailNews = "Email address";
  $('input[name=email]').focus(function() {
    if($(this).val() == defaultEmailNews) $(this).val("");
  });

  $('input[name=email]').focusout(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "") $(this).val(defaultEmailNews);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a shorthand

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".input").val("Email Address");
        $(".input").on("focus click", function(){
            $(this).val("");
        });
    });
</script>
```