# Clear POST data after submission so user can't click Back in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, post

My form when redirected to the thank you page after completion seems to retain all the data in the values field so if the user clicks back everything is there meaning they can just resubmit it and its super annoying.

```
if (emailSent) {
    Response.BufferOutput = true;
    Response.Redirect("MYDOMAIN/redirect.aspx");    
};
```

Above is where I redirect after the form has been submitted. For my code to pull the data I am using:

```
Request.Form[randomFormField]
```

When I redirect and then click back everything is there.

```
$(".submitBut").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
    window.location.href('MYREDIRECTDMAIN/redirect.aspx');
});
```

Above is another one of my attempts

I have tried a variety of different things and nothing seems to work. I need an ASP.NET solution or C# or JQuery.

Comment: Did your boss just ask to "clear all the fields" or are you annoyed by the user being able to (for example) send the same email twice clicking back?

Comment: So when the user clicks back the values are empty I have tried the other users answer and this does not work

Comment: @djechelon Im a junior web developer currently at work

Comment: So when the user clicks back the values are empty I have tried the other users answer and this does not work –  Kieranmv95 6 mins ago

i said this before

Comment: [Here's a useful copy-paste (as in "quick, I'm in a hurry") solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery).

Comment: tried it, didn't work will add it to my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript on page load: clear all form fields

Uhm....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':input').val('');
});
```

References:

1. [Input](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)
2. [Clearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755080/jquery-clear-input-default-value)

Comment: its all still there if I use that method, values are still all filled in

Comment: I wrote code by memory. I'm not 100000% sure it's perfect. Can you see if there are any console messages or errors?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be any console errors, I tried changing it to `$('input').val('');` too but same result :(

Comment: $('input') is wrong in this case. That means "all elements classed input", instead you want all input tags

Comment: Hmmm not working still then, tried a few variations of the original you recommended but everything stays there